# How to setup an implicit FTPS encryption on cPanel server?

Tags: security, cpanel, ftp

Currently my server is configured to use TLS encryption for FTP. It is explicit since it uses FTPES and on port 21. How can I switch to implicit FTPS that works on port 990? I'm using Pure_FTPd. I couldn't find any tutorials for this, it would be great if anyone could point me out to the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Did you contact to your hosting provider? I think they can help you quickly.

Answer (score 1):

All settings available to you in regards to your FTP server are available in WHM (`https://example.net:2087`) under Service Configuration. Assuming you have full root access to your server and cPanel, you could also update the configuration file in `/etc`.